# Unable to Connect to ssl

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, gdata

I have configured the openssl with wamp (Apache server). But while I using gdata api I'm getting following error.

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Exception' with message ' in C:\Zend_1_11_11\library\Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Socket.php on line 234
( ! ) Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Exception: Unable to Connect to ssl://accounts.google.com:443. Error #10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\Zend_1_11_11\library\Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Socket.php on line 234
```

Somebody help me on this...

Comment: Error simply means that you can not connect to target host.Are you able to ping accounts.google.com at least? Are you able to connect to port 443 using opessl command is like "openssl s_client -connect accounts.google.com:443" ?You can try to increase timeout property value

Comment: Thanks for input ,But I am working in  proxy server so I can't ping anything :( . For window I need to install openssl client.
Please let me know may I do something else for workaround..

Comment: You answer to yourself.You are behind proxy.that the reason why you can not connect.

Answer (score 13):

#### Solution only for Windows users:

Check the SSL module is enabled in php.ini:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Comment: That was my first step. By the way I resolved the issue. Thanks @Mikhail

Comment: @Neelesh so what is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Answer from **Mikhail** does not work for me as I run it in Alpine Linux and .dll is only windows extension. Do not use it outside of Windows, it only adds warnings.

**Solved my problem:**

I had a self-signed certificate that was unable to establish connection.

To check that it is problem you can make a request:

wget way:

```
// not working:
wget https://accounts.google.com:443
// working:
wget https://accounts.google.com:443 --no-check-certificate
```

or curl way:

```
// not working:
curl https://accounts.google.com:443
// working:
curl https://accounts.google.com:443 -k
```

To temporary solve it in my dev docker container, I have added use of curl adapter and no check for certificate to the code:

```
    $config = array(
        'adapter'     => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl',
        'curloptions' => [CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false]
    );
    $client = new Zend_Http_Client('https://example.com', $config);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function url_combine()

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions yes, it is my internal function. Changed to some random.

Answer (score 0):

You are behind proxy, so you can not connect directly.Try to use Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Proxy.php instead of Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Socket.php

Comment: Thank you for your help..Could u please help me where from I can change it. I'm newbie in Zend :(

Comment: I changed adapter in client.php Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Proxy but it is also not working...Any help

Answer (score 0):

If you on Ubuntu try add in your `php.ini`

```
openssl.capath=/etc/ssl/certs
```

[For more info read this issue](https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/issues/2535)